# Using svn with project resulting in error

Tags: svn

I just got through installing svn on a droplet I created for repos. I created a repository located here `/home/svn/repos/stack` on the droplet. I then went to my desktop and created a new folder and clicked import (using TortoiseSVN) and I got the following error:

`Unexpected HTTP status  405 'Method Not Allowed' on '/svn/stack'`

and

`PROPFIND request on '/svn/stack' failed: 405 Method Not Allowed`

anyone know how to fix this issue? Am i even doing things in the right order?

Answer (score 0):

I think the folder you are trying to add already exists in svn. You can confirm by checking out the files to a different folder and see if trunk already has the required folder.

so, take folder1 and make a folder1Copy.

```
svn delete folder1
svn add folder1Copy 
commit & update

svn mv folder1Copy/ folder1/
```

commit again and it's fixed.

or

I've solved this issue by setting up HTTPS for the SVN repository. DAV was not allowed by the proxy server but since the proxy server cannot interpret HTTPS it can not block DAV.